# Derivative of spline in casadi

Tags: python, casadi

I am working on an MPC with the python library doMPC and I have to express all my objective functions and constraints using casadi symbolic framework.
I need to use an interpolating cubic spline and use its derivative. However, I cannot find the appropriate way to do it in the documentation. I would really much appreciate your help.
For reference, I used the `interpolant` function :

```py
import casadi as ca

xRef = ca.interpolant("xRef", "bspline", [np.linspace(0, 1, track.shape[1]).tolist()], track[0, :].tolist())
```